# Hierarchy in Qt [C++]

Tags: qt

Guys could any one point it out to me a link to web page where I can find a hierarchy of classes in Qt, preferably as a diagram (something in UML style)? I'm just starting to learn it and I'm finding it quite difficult to work with all these classes - well, mainly with widgets and layouts at the moment- without knowing where they belong.
Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The official class hierarchy is found here:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/hierarchy.html

There are also some class charts. It is really big, you need a plotter to print this in a size which is readable:

- http://doc.qt.digia.com/extras/qt43-class-chart.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing but for QT 5.3. If anyone is interested here you have the class hierarchy for last QT version.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/hierarchy.html

Unfortunately, the classes diagram does not exist as it is mention [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/6865).

Comment: Not sure about Qt 5.3, but the file for Qt 5.5 is at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/hierarchy.html